# Potential of an infinitely long cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, conventions

Suppose I have an infinitely long cylinder with radius $R$, charged with longitudinal density $\lambda$.  I want to calculate the potential outside the cylinder.

The field induced by the cylinder is $\frac{2k\lambda}{r}$, and therefore the potential is

$$
\varphi = 2k\lambda\ln{r} + C
$$

Suppose I set $\varphi = 0$ at $R$, and therefore 
$$
\varphi = 2k\lambda\ln{\left(\frac{r}{R}\right)}
$$

But something isn't right. When $r$ increases, the potential also increases, but this doesn't make sense, because if I am getting further, the potential should decrease not increase, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a sign error. The potential is defined by

[image]

see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential

Comment: In the same article, it is said that the potential is the work done by the electric field. So why there is a minus sign?

Comment: The point is that energy is conserved. When the E-field does work on a particle, the particle's kinetic energy goes up and its potential energy goes down by the same amount so that the total energy stays the same.

Comment: In reply to "work done by the electric field", you are not reading the entire sentence. It is the work done in taking the charge out to infinity. The further out you are from your cylinder, the less work done in taking the charge to infinity, so the potential goes down.

Answer (score -1):

The quantity that you can measure in the lab is the force experienced by a test charge (in reality sensor of some kind). This force is obtained via lorentz force that depends on the electric field. So the physically measurable quantity is the Electric field and not the potential. Remember that $ \vec{E} =-\nabla \phi $ so the electric field decreases with r, and so the force on a test charge will get weaker with r, just as our intuition says.

Comment: So how come weakening the field increases the potential?

Comment: The potential values are not important at all, only it's derivative values matter. Another thing is that @Mark is right, there is a sign correction needed, but it's significance is to treat properly positive and negative charges. The Infinities don't vanish.

Comment: -1 It's true, that the *absolute* potential value does not matter, the *relative* (comparison from different places; the gradient in the end) does! As you pointed out yourself.
Additionally, I **highly doubt** that you measure *electric* fields in your lab with the help of the* Lorentz-force*. How are you supposed to do *that*?
I think your answer is completely wrong.